# User account isolation on multi tenant SharePoint publication

Tags: forms-authentication, multi-tenancy

Does a multi tenant SharePoint web application stores user accounts on "child" websites or in the root web?

I need to provide forms authentication at this multi tenant web application but the users can't be shared between "child" websites and if the user types the root web url, he must be redirected to the "child" website he has permissions (when logging in). Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

All user accounts, regardless of site type, are stored at the Site Collection level.  You'll need to use different Site Collection (using the New-SPSite -SiteSubscription switch).